# Run bash script before opening file

Tags: macos, bash

I would like to run a bash script whenever I double-click on an `.indd` file in OS X. Specifically, when the user double clicks the file, it would run this script in the Terminal:

```
open -a 'InDesign 5.5' myfile.indd
```

Of course, `myfile.indd` would be the file name. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

Are you just trying to get all `indd` files to be opened by InDesign when you double-click them? You can associated files of a given type with a specific application by selecting the file, choose "Get Info" from the "File" menu, and expand the "Open with" pane. From there, select InDesign form the list of applications, click the "Change All..." button, and click OK.

Comment: Yes, sort of, though OSX doesn't allow that when you have both InDesign 5.5 and CS6 installed. Check [this question](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/73286/always-open-a-file-in-a-specific-program) for more info.